# Python matching one list to dict values in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 lists; list one is:

```
a=[500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000]
```

The other is like this:

```
z=[{'1':0},{'2':0},{'3':0},{'4':0},{'5':0}]
```

I have put the dicts in a list, as I want them to remain ordered, so I then run a condition:

```
for elems in a:
    if 2200 < elems:
        NOT SURE?
```

So in this condition what I want to do is, as 2200 is less than 2500 I want the value of the key number 4 in list z to increase by one.

I'm not sure how to achieve this and would like some help please.

Thanks

Comment: Why is `z` a list of one-element dicts and not a list of numbers?

Comment: Or z should perhaps just be a dict with 1-5 as keys?

Comment: @NPE, because I want each value to be updated on this condition. I then want to refer to these values but their key.

Comment: @user1869421 you can get elements from `list`s with the index `[1, 2, 3][1] --> 2`. Note that the index is zero based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having z as a simple list of ints would be enough for what you want to do. Then:

```
z = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for i, elem in enumerate(a):
    if elem > 2200:
         z[i] += 1
```

If you really want that one item dictionary list (assuming length of z and a is same), then you can do:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(a):
    if elem > 2200:
         z[i][str(i+1)] += 1
```

Comment: What I'll be doing next would then be getting each element in the list and dividing by elements in another list. So order is going to be important. What would be the best option?

Comment: If `a = [2, 2, 2]`, `b = [4, 8, 16]`, and you want to get `c = b / a = [2, 4, 8]`, then you can say `c = [ b[i] / elem for i, elem in enumerate(a)]`

Comment: `c = [j/i for i, j in zip(a, b)]` (or use `itertools.izip` as you're using py2.7)

Comment: Yes, that is better actually. Though `c = [j / i for i, j in zip(a, b)]` to be compatible with the example above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate implementation using collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000]

z = Counter(i+1 for i,v in enumerate(a) if v > 2200)
print z

print list({str(a): b} for a, b in z.iteritems())
```

`z` already is what I think is a much more useful form than the desired single-item, string-key items in the list, but as you can see, it can be converted to your preferred format again in a single line.

Output:

```
Counter({5: 1, 6: 1})
[{'5': 1}, {'6': 1}]
```

Comment: +1 nice, Counter is definitely ideal for this- I often forget about it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem

```
a = [500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000]

from collections import defaultdict
z = defaultdict(int)

for i, elems in enumerate(a, 1):
   if 2200 < elems:
       z[i] += 1  # can cast i to str with str(i) to exactly match the keys in the example
```

edit, just noticed your `z` list wasn't zero based